# Pandas line plot with markers based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like following

```
df:

ind group people value value_50
 1      1    5    100    1
 1      2    2    90     1
 2      1    10   80     1
 2      2    20   40     0
 3      1    7    10     0
 3      2    23   30     0
```

And I tried to pivot them, to see 'group' individual metrics in columns

```
df = data.pivot_table(index = data.ind, columns = ['group'], values = ['people', 'value','value_50'])
df
```

And then tried to plot 'value' for both groups separately with "ind" on x axis

```
df.plot()
```

[image]

but I dont want to include all the columns in graph, instead I am trying to color marker based on df['value_50'] and a size bubble or size marker based on df['people'] as c and s paramteres respectively.

It will help to identify certain points on the graph

```
df['value'].plot(c =df['value_50'], s = df['value'])
```

but receiving an error

```
AttributeError: Unknown property s
```

And also is it possible with cufflinks also, because I have tried

```
 df['value'].iplot(c =df['value_50'], s = df['value'])
```

Again failed to do so

how to perform it with pandas/ cufflinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for plotly express, but It would be almost as easy and way more flexible to use `plotly.graph_objs`.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# plotly setup and traces
fig = go.Figure()

# lines 1
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['value'][1].values,
                                 name = 'value_1',
                                 mode = 'lines'))

# lines 2
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['value'][2].values,
                                 name = 'value_2',
                                 mode = 'lines'))


# markers 1
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['value'][1].values,
                                 name = 'people',
                                 mode = 'markers',
                                 marker=dict(color=df['value_50'][1], colorscale='viridis', colorbar=dict(title='value_50')),
                                 marker_size=df['people'][1]*1.8
                        )

             )

# markers 2
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['value'][2].values,
                                 name = 'people',
                                 mode = 'markers',
                                 marker=dict(color=df['value_50'][2], colorscale='viridis', colorbar=dict(title='value_50')),
                                 marker_size=df['people'][2]*1.8
                        )

             )

# adjust and show final figure
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(x=-.15, y=1))
fig.show()
```

I'm still not 100% sure what you'er aiming to do here. Let me know how this works for you and we can have a look at the details.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `matplotlib` to graph the data in the way you want. To recap your question, you were looking to plot data with `value` in the y axis and `ind` in the x axs, and each specific point size will be based on the value in the `people` column. The whole graph being divided between each group.

**Pivot DF**

```
df_pv = df.pivot(index='ind', columns='group', values=['people', 'value', 'value_50'])

>> out

       people   value   value_50
group   1   2   1   2   1   2
ind                     
1       5   2   100 90  1   1
2       10  20  80  40  1   0
3       7   23  10  30  0   0
```

**Graph**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(10,5))

ind = df_pv.index.values
# generate random hex color & create as many colors as groups.
r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
colors = ['#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(), r(), r()) for i in range(len(df_pv.people.columns.values))]
labels = df_pv.people.columns.values

for i in range(len(df_pv.people.values[0])):
    val = df_pv.value.values[:,i]
    peop = df_pv.people.values[:,i]
    for j in range(len(peop)):
        plt.scatter(x=[ind[j]], y=[val[j]],
                marker='o', linestyle='--',s=peop[j]*7, color=colors[i])

    plt.plot(ind, val, color=colors[i], label=f'Group: {labels[i]}')

plt.legend()
plt.xticks(df_pv.index.unique())
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.xlabel('Ind')
plt.title('Graph')
plt.show()
```

[image]

My hope, at first, was to create the graph and access each individual marker to set the size. Unfortunately I was not able to find a solution leading this way.

Instead, we are ploting each individual point for each group using `plt.scatter()`. Here we assign the size of the point based on the people column for the specific group. We then connect each point using `plt.plot()` and assign the label and the color.

The code as been write to accept n different groups without having to assign any value manually (colors, points, etc.).